# Render partial view in specific div

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to create a dynamic gird, or one that appears to be dynamic. My goal is to be able to search, view, edit and delete records from a single view using partial views. I'd like it to behavior similarly to the ASP.NET WebForms gridview.

Basically I have a table with three columns. One is for the ID, the other for the Name. The third will hold simple commands such as "Save", "Update", "Cancel" so on and so forth.

I have separate views for "_Create", "_Edit" and "_Delete". Currently, I'm rending them using this method:

```
 public ActionResult RenderPartialView(string view, int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return PartialView(view);
            }
            else
            {
                ProjectData item = new ProjectData();                

                //populate data 
                return PartialView(view, item);
            }
        }

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "RenderPartialView", new { view = "_Edit", id = @model.ID.ToString() })
```

This does render the partial view with the correct data, however it does not display it in the specific div the correlates to that record. Here is what the view from the table and records looks like:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Source)
    {
        <div id="@item.ProjectID">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "RenderPartialView", new { view = "_Edit", id = @item.ProjectID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    }
```

My partial view looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Project", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = @Model.ProjectID.ToString(), HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ProjectID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Name)
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Save")
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "RenderPartialView", new { view = "???", id = "" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

How do I go about rendering the partial view, in this case "_Edit" in the specific div? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if forms and tables can be mixed in that way. If jQuery is an option, I would bind the "Edit" button to a jQuery ajax get and update the target div with the partial view. Then, on "Save", I would make an ajax post with the edited data and, again, update the div.

Comment: @AndreiV, I'm looking into it now. Thanks!

Comment: maybe take a look at the PartialViewResult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Your html structure is not perfect.. Why are you mixing the form in place of tr? please write a proper HTML

Comment: @Murali because each row is essential it's own separate form. I don't want to submit them as a whole, just individually.

Comment: Your case, the html skeleton should be like `<table> for-each<tr><td><form>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to display in the td, you need:

```
@Html.Action(...)
```

Not:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "RenderPartialView"
```